# FlexSlider not scaling slides down when slider is inside fixed positioned element

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, flexslider

I am using the [FlexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) jQuery plugin to run a slider on my site's homepage. I picked this slider because it is responsive. The big problem I'm having with it is that I have it inside of a `position:fixed` element and it is causing problems with the responsive scaling. When I make my browser window wider the slides scale up, awesome. However when I scale the window down the slides do not scale back down. This only happens when the slider is located within a fixed element. This problem also happens with the demo that FlexSlider provides. In the demo to make it break all you have to do is add `position:fixed` to the `<section class="slider">` element.

Does anybody have an ideas on a workaround for this problem? Changing my container element to something other than fixed is not an option.

Comment: Could you add another element inside the position:fixed one with position:relative and see if that works?

Comment: Tried it. Didn't fix the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it. I needed to set the width of the fixed element. `width:100%` worked.